# Publish via FTP publish profile not working using dotnet CLI

Tags: c#, .net-core, ftp, dotnet-cli

I am trying to deploy Asp.Net core 3.1 application using FTP publish profile.
By visual studio its works fine
but using dotnet CLI it ignores the FTP publish profile.

My FTP publish profile looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FTP</WebPublishMethod>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    </SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>dd4a9fd0-9d74-43ae-a752-4e60e7ac9fbc</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>ftp://***.***.****.com/</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <FtpPassiveMode>True</FtpPassiveMode>
    <FtpSitePath>
    </FtpSitePath>
    <UserName>ftpdeploy</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I have tried

```
dotnet build "AsyncTomTomDemo.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="FTPProfile" /p:Username="ftpdeploy" /p:Password="*******"
```

And

```
dotnet publish "AsyncTomTomDemo.csproj" /p:PublishProfile="FTPProfile" /p:Username="ftpdeploy" /p:Password="Ftpdepl0y@21"
```

It publishes at the default location "bin\debug.netcore3.1..." instead of FTP server

Here is the log it generates

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  AsyncTomTomDemo -> C:\JenkinsData\workspace\FTPDeployTest\AsyncTomTomDemo\AsyncTomTomDemo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\AsyncTomTomDemo.dll
  AsyncTomTomDemo -> C:\JenkinsData\workspace\FTPDeployTest\AsyncTomTomDemo\AsyncTomTomDemo\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.10
```

If I create Folder profile this same command works.

Comment: What does your FTP publishing profile look like?

Comment: I have updated question and added publish profile in question.